# Google Drive SDK for iOS: issue with queries

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I've run into issue with GTLQueryDrive.
Callbacks from `queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"` & `queryForFilesList` methods return 0 items. `NSLog(@"files count: %d", files.items.count)` gives me 0.

https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/objectivec - I'm using this example to play with Drive APIs, just removed search restriction - `query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";` to get all files.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you specify kGTLAuthScopeDrive.  I made the mistake of using kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile from the sample app; this restricts the scope to only the files created by your app, while kGTLAuthScopeDrive gives your app access to all the user's files.

Also, for the 'root' query, add @"'root' in parents and trashed=false" to youer query.q.  For example mine looks like this:

> ```
> GTLQueryDrive *query;
> ```

```
if ([self isRoot])
{
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];
    query.q = @"'root' in parents and trashed=false";
}
else
{
    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:self.metadata.identifier];
    query.q = @"trashed=false";
}
```